# Disable fast forward in video player

Tags: video, wordpress, video-streaming, wordpress-theming

Can any one suggest a WordPress Video plugin or any other way to accomplish

a) Disable fast forward on a video where people would go to the end?

b) Perhaps have the video go to a "success" page that would then mark that member as completed that video module?

Any help please.....?

Answer (score 2):

Go for a Custom Flash Player by doing so you will have the flexibility to track the overall progress of the video as well as you can integrate any business logic on top of that.

For a simple video player try [this](http://www.ilike2flash.com/2011/11/simple-as3-video-player-using.html).